Calculating the heat of reaction between sulfuric acid and sodium hydroxide
For my lab report I have to calculate the theoretical heat of reaction $\Delta H_{\text{rxn}}$ between sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$ and sodium hydroxide $\ce{NaOH}$ using their heat of formations. The reaction I have is $$\ce{H2SO4 (aq) + 2NaOH (aq) -> Na2SO4 (aq) + 2H2O (l)}$$
Now because the sulfuric acid, sodium hydroxide, and sodium sulfate are all aqueous, I thought to use the enthalpy of formation $\Delta H^\circ_f$ for their ions, especially because I couldn't find any value of $\Delta H^\circ_f$ for aqueous sulfuric acid (could only find liquid).
The problem is that my instructor said I'd have to be a little careful about sulfuric acid because it would dissociate into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{HSO4-}$, which I'm guessing is because hydrogen sulfate is a weak acid itself. But when I write the ionic equation, I get $$\ce{H+ (aq) + HSO4- (aq) + 2Na+ (aq) + 2OH- (aq) -> 2Na+ (aq) + H2O (l) + HSO4- (aq) + OH- (aq)}$$
Which would translate to a net ionic equation of $$\ce{H+ (aq) + OH- (aq) -> H2O (l)}$$
Now when I calculate the heat of reaction from this, I get around $-55.9\dfrac{\text{kJ}}{\text{mol}}$. But my experimental data showed that $0.02$ moles of sulfuric acid and $0.04$ moles of sodium hydroxide produced $\approx2259$ Joules of energy, which translates to 113 kJ/mol.
I don't know where I'm going wrong with this.

Hydrogen sulfate is strong enough, mostly dissociated in diluted solutions. You could only ignore it, if it was very weak.

You were too careful and did not think! there were two moles of H+ and OH-.

@jimchmst I understand that there would be two moles of H+ and OH-, but the point was that the hydrogen sulfate ion (HSO4-) wouldn't completely dissociate, and so one of the OH- would be a spectator ion and the H in hydrogen sulfate would not dissociate. The commenters helpfully pointed out that the weakness of HSO4- was not enough to disregard its contribution to the total change in enthalpy.

The reaction with OH- forces the dissociation. Since HSO4- is still relatively strong its heat of neutralization is almost the same as H3O+. A weaker acid will have a lower heat of neutralization. OH- is a spectator ion only after all acids are neutralized and it is added in excess.




Arbitrary representation
Species
$\Delta H_f^o\;$ [kJ/mol]




A
$\ce{H2SO4(aq)}$
-909.27


B
$\ce{NaOH(aq)}$
-469.15


C
$\ce{Na2SO4(aq)}$
-1387.10


D
$\ce{H2O(l)}$
-285.83



The reaction we have is:
$$\ce{A(aq) +2B(aq)->C(aq) +2D(l)}$$
The standard molar change in enthalpy for this reaction is given by:
$$\Delta\overline{H}^o=c\;\Delta\overline{H}_{f_C}^o\;+\;d\;\Delta\overline{H}_{f_D}^o\;-\;\left(a\;\Delta\overline{H}_{f_A}^o\;+\;b\;\Delta\overline{H}_{f_B}^o\right)$$
Substituting the values from the table:
$$\Delta \overline{H}^o=-1387.10+2(-285.83)-[-909.27-2(469.15)]$$
$$\pmb{\boxed{\Delta \overline{H}^o=\pu{-111.19kJ/mol}}}$$
Calculating the standard change in enthalpy with amounts of reactants used:
$$\Delta H^o=\frac{n_A\;\Delta \overline{H}^o}{a}=\frac{\pu{(0.02mol)(\pu{-111.19kJ/mol})}}{1}=\pu{-2.22kJ}=\pu{-2220J}$$
Aside from minor, expected error related to experimental measurements, you have obtained a reasonably accurate result with a small relative error:
$$E=\frac{\left|111.19-113\right|}{111.19}=0.0163=1.63\%$$

The problem is difficult to handle, because of the extraordinary changes in the heats of dilution of $\ce{H2SO4}$ in water. The amount of heat produced by mixing $1.000$ mole $\ce{H2SO4}$ with $n$ mole water has been determined in the Journal of Chemical Education $81, 7$, July $2004$, p. $993$. The main results are summarized here :
$n$ = $1$ mol water :  $28.08$ kJ ;
$n$ = $2$ mol water :  $41.93$ kJ
$n$ = $4$ mol water :  $54.07$ kJ
$n$ = $10$ mol water : $67.04$ kJ
$n$ = $20$ mol water : $72.69$ kJ
$n$ = $50$ mol water : $73.36$ kJ - Gives a solution $1.00$ M.
$n$ = $500$ mol water : $76.75$ kJ - Gives a solution $0.100$ M
$n$ = $2000$ mol water : $80.90$ kJ
$n$ = $10 000$ mol water : $87.09$ kJ
$n$ = $100 000$ mol water ; $93.66$ kJ
$n$ = ∞ mol water :    $96.26$ kJ
The heat of dilution is a continuous function of the amount of added water. So it is difficult to use these values to calculate precise heats of neutralization of any acidic solution with any $\ce{NaOH}$ solutions.

titration usually involves a small change in total volume mitigating, but not eliminating, this effect.
